# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int16' to my Enum variable

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, .net-core

I'm tryng to convert a numeric type on my mysql database (smallint(6)) and I'm getting the following error:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int16' to type 'MyEnum'.

My Enum is:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    Value1 = 1,
    Value2 = 2,
    Value3 = 3,
    Value4 = 4
}
```

The conversion is happening here:

```
MyEnum enumHere = (MyEnum)reader["cod_sist_orig"];
```

Reader is a IDataReader and the column is a not nullable column and the value comming from the database is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need cast to `short` first:

```cs
MyEnum enumHere = (MyEnum)(short)reader["cod_sist_orig"];
```

Or change the enum's underlying type to `short`:

```cs
public enum MyEnum : short
{
    Value1 = 1,
    Value2 = 2,
    Value3 = 3,
    Value4 = 4
}
```

For more info check out the docs for [unboxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing#unboxing) and relevant part of the [language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#unboxing-conversions).